# Method or way to get notiified about the next segment in DASH protocol

Tags: javascript, mpeg-dash

I'm relatively new to DASH and js but i was wondering in dash player if there is any method to call to be notified when the currently downloaded segment is finished so that i do some other things before i start downloading the next .

I looked at the REST API of dash but did not find anything.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Which player are you using? There are several ones, like [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/), [Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/video-player/), or [Shaka](https://github.com/google/shaka-player/).
And which REST API are you talking about?

Comment: I'm using dash.js . The REST API I'm talking about is this http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/module-MediaPlayer.html .

But i cannot find a way to get the current segment downloading info, ie which index it is and when it has finished downloading.

Comment: I don't think DASH.js supports an event like this at this time - see some discussion here which may be relevant: https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/857